# Python selenuim) How can I click a button in Modal?

Tags: python, html, selenium

(updated question)

Hi.

I'm trying to click a button but it doesn't work.
I guess the error cause by Modal tags. But I'm not sure.

I got `"NoSuchElementException"` Error before I import `"webdriver.support"`, Now I get `"TimeoutException"` error. I can't find a way. Can you help me?

**ERROR**

```
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
```

**Button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"> 반출기본정보 수정</button>
```

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Login

# put id
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://po-management.net/release/list")
time.sleep(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.send_keys(usernameStr)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(2)

# put password
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input73"]')
try:
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).send_keys(passwordStr).perform()
    password.send_keys(passwordStr)
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# redirect
time.sleep(3)
url = "https://po-management.net/release/list"
driver.get(url)

# search
time.sleep(1)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("releaseSeqArray")
search.send_keys(vrorder)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# click1
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_link_text(vrorder).click()

# click2
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-warning.btn-sm#btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"))).click()
```

Comment: Have you tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#btnReleaseVendorInfoModal").click()`

Comment: Yes. I get error "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button#btnReleaseVendorInfoModal"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)"

Comment: Can you share the link to the site?

Comment: Sorry. It is company internal website. So imposible to be loaded fron outside

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: without access to page it is hard to say something. Maybe it is in `<frame>` and then it needs `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the the frame by doing :

```
# after the frame is activated/displayed
modal = driver.find_element_by_id('releaseCauseInfo')
driver.switch_to_frame(modal)

# all the code that interacts with the modal can come here
```

**NB:** Don't forget to switch back to the default window after you're done with the modal by using `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: Thansk for answer. But it doesn't still work with error "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="releaseCauseInfo"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)"

Comment: This means the error is with identifying the modal let alone interacting with it. I'm guessing the modal has not loaded at the point at which you are looking for it